# What should be the leagth of int in a sql table where i store the facebook profile id?

Tags: mysql, sql, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Most often i work with cms but did not worked with sql directly too much before. I am making a facebook page directory where i am saving page ids the length of facebook page id is 10-13 digit sometimes. So what types of int i should use. I am thinking about `BIGINT` but what should be the length of it ?

Here is the table visually. I would be glad if you can advice the length of the fields.[image: Database Table]

**Here is the datatype and length i comeup with. But i am confused if these are efficient:**

1. **ID:** Database id for the pages (int 5)
2. **page_id**: Facebook page id (bigint)
3. **page_name:** Facebook page name (varchar 50)
4. **username:** username of the page (varchar 50)
5. **likes:** number of likes (int)
6. **Link:** Link to the page (varchar 100)
7. **Time_added:** current timestamp

Comment: Is the page ID specified to be an integer, or might it be a (mostly numeric) alphanumeric character array? I don't know the Facebook API, but it might be worth a lookup.

Comment: @Mudu: facebook page id is integer.

Comment: OK. I had a look at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/ before, which isn't the `Page`, is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct, you'll need a `BIGINT`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-types.html.

I'd recommend longer lengths for your `VARCHAR` fields.  It won't hurt anything, and URLs in particular can get very long.  I'd probably bump up the two 50-character fields to 100, and allow for 1,000 characters in the Link field.

Answer (score 6):

As you don't have control over what Facebook might do in the future, I'd use a type that is least sensitive to change.

As you won't be doing an arithmetic manipulation to the page_id, I'd store it as a varchar.

Comment: +1 for `VARCHAR`. It would hardly be shocking for Facebook to change the format in the future.

Answer (score 3):

the easiest thing is to treat those IDs as string or varchar with 15 characters.
using php it can cause problems when working with 64-bit integers.

the performance difference is negligible!